# segmentaion fault on linux 4.14.304 when run "perf record"

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, kernel, arm64, perf

I run "perf record" and it crashes:

```
# perf record
[ 5574.631385] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffff80087497a9
[ 5574.639299] Mem abort info:
[ 5574.640708]   Exception class = DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
[ 5574.647987]   SET = 0, FnV = 0
[ 5574.651066]   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
[ 5574.651853] Data abort info:
[ 5574.655239]   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000007
[ 5574.659753]   CM = 0, WnR = 0
[ 5574.663848] swapper pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgd = ffffff8008812000
[ 5574.670636] [ffffff80087497a9] *pgd=000000007bffe003, *pud=000000007bffe003, *pmd=000000007bffb003, *pte=0000000000000000
[ 5574.681598] Internal error: Oops: 96000007 [#13] PREEMPT SMP
[ 5574.687252] Modules linked in: rp3(O) csd(O) ultxrxcccorr(O) ultxrxcc(O) tmr(O) swi(O) str(O) pcs(O) mes(O) jsd(O) esds(O) esdl(O) esdc(O) esdb(O) dul(O) ddl(O) ctx_bank(O) ctx(O) c)
[ 5574.732494] Process perf (pid: 3337, stack limit = 0xffffff8014978000)
[ 5574.736844] CPU: 2 PID: 3337 Comm: perf Tainted: G      D    O    4.14.304 #1
[ 5574.743959] Hardware name: Made SoC (DT)
[ 5574.750037] task: ffffffc078f36c00 task.stack: ffffff8014978000
[ 5574.755950] pc : get_ctx+0x0/0x50
[ 5574.759257] lr : find_get_context.isra.0+0x194/0x288
[ 5574.764211] sp : ffffff801497bd70 pstate : 00000145
[ 5574.766821] x29: ffffff801497bd70 x28: 0000000000000000
[ 5574.774374] x27: 0000000000000000 x26: 0000000000000000
[ 5574.779678] x25: ffffffc07b10fe80 x24: 0000000000000000
[ 5574.783593] x23: 0000000000000004 x22: 00000000ffffffff
[ 5574.790278] x21: ffffffc07b10fe80 x20: ffffff8008749729
[ 5574.795583] x19: ffffff8008749721 x18: 0000000000000001
[ 5574.800887] x17: 0000007f9ddfd300 x16: ffffff800812aba0
[ 5574.806191] x15: 0000000000000000 x14: 0000000000000000
[ 5574.810887] x13: 0000000300000002 x12: 0000000100000000
[ 5574.815748] x11: 0000000000000040 x10: ffffff80087f2b30
[ 5574.819481] x9 : ffffffc07898d810 x8 : ffffffc06dc77b78
[ 5574.824777] x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffffffc06dc77b50
[ 5574.832678] x5 : ffffffc06dc77b80 x4 : ffffff8008768708
[ 5574.837982] x3 : 0000000000000001 x2 : ffffffc078f36c00
[ 5574.843286] x1 : 0000000000400100 x0 : ffffff8008749721
[ 5574.848591] Call trace:
[ 5574.851029]  get_ctx+0x0/0x50
[ 5574.853989]  SyS_perf_event_open+0x43c/0xdc0
[ 5574.858251]  el0_svc_naked+0x34/0x38
[ 5574.859214] Code: f9414c21 9411391a 17fffff5 d503201f (b9408801)
[ 5574.867895] ---[ end trace 6ee5d32e2ee2eebe ]---
Segmentation fault
ftp@made-Node0:/var/tmp#
```

I tried a 5.10 based image, 'perf record' runs well, but I have to have it with 4.14 image.
I searched the web and no exact issue found, similar issues are rare and dates back many days and no help to solve my issue.
I have limited knowledge in this scope, can anybody help me?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the old kernel version; I think kernel code always aims to avoid a situation like this happening in the first place.  Perhaps there's a bugfix commit you could backport, if you can find it.  (If it was fixed as part of a rewrite of something, that would be harder to backport.)  If it's a distro "stable" kernel, maybe they can find and backport the fix if you report thi bug, otherwise you might have to do it yourself.